# How do I view an AVI file that requires GTCC codec?

Tags: video, codec, video-playback, decoding

I have pretty much tried every type of decoder package out there (K-lite, CCCP, Satsuki, etc.) but no luck. I used an old webcam back in the early 2000s when recording. Really need to know what this video has.

Comment: There are programs out there like "media info" that would analise the header of the media file and provide info about most known codecs and the 4cs, and other observerd aspects seen in the header. sourceforge.net/projects/mediainfo it can be better to see than to start adding messes of codec packs into a computer. I doubt something that obscure would be in it, but it might provide more general info about the media item. Disclaimer: Be careful with the install of even this well known tool, a user suggested it has added crap in the install.

Comment: Some information here: http://www.moviecodec.com/video-codecs/fourcc-gtcc-codec-1184/